# Can I use three ways comparison (<=>) using g++?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

I want to try to use the three ways comparison operator (`<=>`) but...

code:

```
#include <compare>

int main(){
  .
  .
  .
}
```

command:

```
g++ -std=c++2a compare.cpp
```

output:

```
compare.cpp:10:10: fatal error: compare: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <compare>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I couldn't find any solution to fix this error. I’m using g++ 9.3.0.

Hasn't g++ supported `<compare>` yet?
If it has, how can I fix this error using g++?
Or if it hasn't, please teach me another way to use `<compare>`, without g++.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Try [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) at least.

Comment: Here's the list of features and their compiler support https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support - I suggest you consult it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! By default, g++ doesn't necessarily use the latest version of the standard, so that code written for an older version continues to compile in a predictable way. So you might need to pass a switch to get it to use a later version, like `-std=c++20` (or `-std=c++2a` in GCC 9).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've used g++ 9.3.0,  and now I'll install and try gcc10.

Comment: Read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx2a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use three ways comparison (<=>) using g++?

Yes, this [does work](https://godbolt.org/z/nq6MxT).

But remember that, as commenters note:

1. It has to be a sufficiently recent version of GCC - 10.x at least
2. This header, and the spaceship operator `<=>`, are part of the C++20 language standard. So you have to specify `-std=c++20` (or `-std=c++2a` in earlier versions) to ensure they can be used.

Comment: `-std=c++20` made the difference for me. So the full command for me is `g++ "-static" -o main.exe .\*.cpp -std=c++20`